# Display output as CSV in Python using Pandas

Tags: python

Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.vanglaini.org/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    headline = article.a.text
    summary=article.p.text
    link = "https://www.vanglaini.org" +article.a['href']
    #print(headline)
    #print(summary)
    #print(link)

#print()

news_csv = pd.DataFrame({'Headline': headline,
                         'Summary': summary,
                        'Link' : link,


                         })
print(news_csv)
```

**i got this error**
headline = article.a.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Help!

Comment: Are you sure there is articles fields in the page you are looking for?

Comment: I can print headline, summary and  link. Just wanted to display as csv/csv file

Comment: article has no a attribute

Comment: Please help me modify the code Please

Comment: you got answer in my comment in previous question - it seems not all articles have link so `article.a` gives `None` and you can't get `None.text` . You have to check `if article.a is None:` . And error `raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index") ` is for different reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already get in my comments and in @AmiTavory (deleted) answer - not all articles have link and sometimes `article.a` gives `None` so you have `None.text` which gives you error.

You have to check if `article.a` is not `None` like

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.vanglaini.org/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    if article.a is None:
        continue        

    headline = article.a.text
    summary = article.p.text
    link = "https://www.vanglaini.org" + article.a['href']
    print(headline)
    print(summary)
    print(link)
```

and it works.

---

**EDIT:** You can get error

```
raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index") ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

for totally different reason and you should create new question on new page.

It is problem in `DataFrame` because you have only last value in `headline`, `summary`, `link` but `DataFrame` expects lists in

```
{
    'Headline': list_with_headlines,
    'Summary': list_with_summaries,
    'Link' : list_with_links,
}
```

You should create empty lists before `for`-loop

```
list_with_headlines = []
list_with_summaries = []
list_with_links = []
```

and inside `for`-loop you should`append()` values to lists

```
list_with_headlines.append(headline)
list_with_summaries.append(summary)
list_with_links.append(link)
```

and later create `DataFrame` using lists

```
news_csv = pd.DataFrame({
    'Headline': list_with_headlines,
    'Summary': list_with_summaries,
    'Link' : list_with_links,
})
```

---

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.vanglaini.org/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

list_with_headlines = []
list_with_summaries = []
list_with_links = []

for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    if article.a is None:
        continue        
    headline = article.a.text.strip()
    summary = article.p.text.strip()
    link = "https://www.vanglaini.org" + article.a['href']
    list_with_headlines.append(headline)
    list_with_summaries.append(summary)
    list_with_links.append(link)

news_csv = pd.DataFrame({
    'Headline': list_with_headlines,
    'Summary': list_with_summaries,
    'Link' : list_with_links,
})

print(news_csv)
```